# Just installed Unbunto via Windows XP and cant log in

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have an eePC 904 with Windows XP.  Today I downloaded the Windows installer and it worked just fine.  When I came to log in, it tells me my login and password are wrong...its asking for the "root" login info?  Total newbie so am a tad dumbfounded.

I have noted a number of discussion re upgrading and people having the same issue.  I've tried some of their suggestions with no luck...

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Wubi has bugs like that, it is better to install Ubuntu via a live CD or a USB device.
You can uninstall Ubuntu by going onto Windows XP -> Control Panel -> Add or remove software -> Ubuntu / Wubi

Live CD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD